# The mathematical formulation of LSTM in Keras?

Tags: keras, lstm, keras-layer

According to the mathematical formulation from [wikipedia-lstm-math-equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory), as shown below, 
[image: LSTM Equation]

there should be only hidden state `h_t` and cell state `c_t`. However, when I tried to write RNN code on Keras, there are three: `lstm_output`, `state_h` and `state_c`.

I am now wondering what is the mathematical formulation of `lstm_output`?
Here is my code:

```
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM

lstm_input = Input(shape=(28, 10))

lstm_output, state_h, state_c = LSTM(units=32,
                                     return_sequences=True,
                                     return_state=True,
                                     unroll=True)(lstm_input)
print(lstm_output, state_h, state_c)
```

and it gives

```
Using TensorFlow backend.

(<tf.Tensor 'lstm_1/transpose_1:0' shape=(?, 28, 32) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'lstm_1/mul_167:0' shape=(?, 32) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'lstm_1/add_221:0' shape=(?, 32) dtype=float32>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down, looking at [this line](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2023) from the source code - `return h, [h, c]`:

- **lstm_output:** is the `h` of each time step. So it has shape `(batch_size, sequence_length, hidden_size)`, in your case it is `(?, 28, 32)`. As the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) says, it is returned as a sequence because you set `return_sequences=True`.
- **state_h:** is the *last* timestep's `h` and if you can check, it should be equal to `lstm_output[:,-1]`. Notice why it's shape is `(?, 32)`, since it is the last timestep's output, not at every timestep.
- **state_c:** is the *last* timestep's `c`.

The equations are often implemented in different ways to optimise for certain features but they all follow the [original paper](http://www.bioinf.jku.at/publications/older/2604.pdf). Note that there might be variations on the activations such as using `hard_sigmoid` for the recurrent activiation and these should be clearly noted in the documentation.

Comment: Not because of `return_sequences`, the layer's output is always returned, of course. It's what every layer do. --- `return_sequences` will define whether the output will have the entire sequence or just the last step.

Comment: Thanks for both of your helpful answer and comment. I've tried two kinds of cases. First, `return_sequences=True, return_state=True`, it'll give `lstm_output`(3D), `state_h`(2D), `state_c`(2D) and `lstm_output[:, -1, :]` equals to `state_h`. Second, `return_sequences=False, return_state=True`, it gives `lstm_output`(2D), `state_h`(2D), `state_c`(2D) and `lstm_output` equals to `state_h`.